# start new script if last script is not execute with in minute

Tags: shell-script, shell, delay

I have too many entry in cron tab to run script at every half hour (more than 50 script).

At every half hour all script will executed simultaneously so that server load will increase due to starting of more than 50 process at a time.

To overcome I have set crontab that will execute one shell script and in this shell script all script will be executed one by one.

for example **allscript.sh** will executed from crontab

**allscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
a.sh
b.sh
c.sh
d.sh
.
.
.
ay.sh
```

But in one by one execution if one script take too many time (5 minute) then other script have to wait for specific time. So I want to set in this script if any process take more than one minute then automatically other script's execution will start.

Comment: this is bordering on a scheduling tool. do all files must be run in order ? can some be run in parallel ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a job queue. Likely what you'll do is setup a job queue with one thread per core. This allows all your jobs to queue in one operation + if one job takes longer than others, then the others will be running in other threads.

There are many ways to accomplish this.

Here are a few searches which my help you.

[ubuntu job queue](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu%20job%20queue&oq=ubuntu%20job%20queue&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i64.7064j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[bash job queue](https://www.google.com/search?ei=W6IFWrDgCIiUjwS4l6CwDg&q=bash%20job%20queue&oq=bash%20job%20queue&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i7i30k1.167730.168055.0.168302.4.4.0.0.0.0.89.333.4.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.333....0.VtgkEvfAULM)